# Inverse Property on Alternative Key

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-3.0

Is it possible to create an inverse property based on an alternative key in ef core?

```cs
public class Profile 
{
    public int ProfileId { get; set; }

    public int? SubProfileId { get; set; }

    public SubProfile SubProfile {get;set;

    [InverseProperty(nameof(OtherEntity.Profile)]
    public ICollection<OtherEntity> OtherEntities { get; set; }

    // Is there away to achieve this without ef core doing what ef core does "best" 
    // and do funky things, as it does in this case and add "hidden" properties to the sql table?
    [InverseProperty(nameof(OtherSubEntity.SubProfile)]
    public ICollection<OtherSubEntity> OtherSubEntities { get; set; }
}
```

If I have a entity as defined above is there away to achieve that second inverse property without ef core adding custom properties to OtherSubEntity that it creates in SQL.

Comment: Does OtherSubEntity have foreign key properties to store the Profile key value?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft In this scenario, unfortunately not. But it did just open up an idea for a work around. It would still be cool to know if this is possible

Comment: Foreign keys are required.  If you don't have them (or don't map them) EF will create a shadow property.

Comment: Looks like `OtherSubEntities` is placed at the wrong place - it should be in `SubProfile` class. In `Profile` it could be accessed through `SubProfile` navigation property, e.g. `profile.SubProfile.OtherSubEntities`.